# Image before td tags in table

Tags: html, css

[image]

How do i position an image / div behind the TDs like on the image above

Comment: Is the image part of the `table` structure? What does your markup look like?

Comment: no it isnt part of the table structure.

Comment: Try float:left kind of thing

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve by trying like this.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.image {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  
}
.image img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.table {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
table td {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/beautiful_scenery_04_hd_pictures_166258.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <table>
      <tr><td>TD Data 1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>TD Data 2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>TD Data 3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>TD Data 4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>TD Data 5</td></tr>
     
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate all the td tags together and have the image tag before it and then displayed with 'inline' style property.

Basic structure would be like -

```
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <img/>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
      <table>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Minor thing, but your table rows should be contained within a table for valid markup.

Comment: Thanks @UncaughtTypeError have fixed the same.